# Face color not being inherited

Tags: faces

I am trying to have a face inherit styling (strikethrough) and color from another face.

Specifically, I want the `org-agenda-done` to inherit from `org-headline-done`.

In the Customize UI, I see the inherit preview, I see the correct style, but the color is not being applied in the top preview.

I would expect this to change color and strikethrough. Why are both not being applied?

[image]

Comment: You have to at least hit "Apply" before the change takes effect (the button should be at the top of the buffer).   The "State" button is telling you this...

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. The top preview updates to include the strikethrough, but the color does not change when applying and saving changes.